# How to recompile and run a prebuilt linux kernel driver as a custom module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules, serial-port

I am able to create a custom basic module (hello wrold kernel) and use `insmod` to load it into kernel space. However what I need now is to be able to use `slip.c` code by its entirety (copy and paste) into my own module and compile and run effectively. This way, the new module with slip sourcecode compiles, successfully insterted into kernel space by `insmod`, but, does not function as it should: running `sudo slattach -p my_slip_replica -s 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0 -m &` retruns with the error `Hardware type my_slip_replica not supported. [1]+ Exit 1`. By default, the linux kernel has `slip.ko` object file already compiled at `/lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/net/slip` and `modprobe slip` loads the module and indeed functions with no problems at all.

So my question is, **how can I replicate slip.c** (plus slip.h and possible a few more files) **and run successfully**?